# cURL request without waiting for the response

Tags: php, curl

How do you send a request without waiting for a response & without using AJAX? With cURL, I only know to how to shorten the time by setting the CURLOPT_TIMEOUT as low as possible (1 second), but this still means cURL request takes 1 second:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://example.com?action=example');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You cant do asynchronous requests with curl, your need to use sockets, remove `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);` and use `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS` instead of `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT`, then it wont wait, but dont expect to be able to get the result.. this is why work queues and background tasks were invented.. use right tool for job, just dont do it inline.

Answer (score 0):

if your problem is the web browser waiting time, making the browser wait via XMLHttpRequest (/AJAX) is probably a better solution. libcurl has async functionality, but it won't help your page load speed in PHP unless you're also running php behind fastcgi (because you'd need php to support `fastcgi_finish_request();` to send the page to the browser before php has finished running) - my recommendation: use ajax instead of adding a fastcgi dependency and async curl code.

Comment: Is there a problem doing it like this: `exec('curl http://example.com/example > /dev/null 2>&1 &');` This seems like the best way to do async requests without having to use AJAX.